# Three.jsで動作させることが可能な3Dキャラクターは、どうやって作成するのですか？

Tags: three.js

Three.jsで、3Dキャラクターをインタラクティブに動作させてみたいのですが、
Three.jsで動作させることが可能な3Dキャラクターは、どうやって作成するのですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3Dキャラクターは3DCG作成ソフトウェアを使って作成します。

あくまで一例ですが、個人用途では例えば[Blender](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender)というオープンソースソフトウェアを利用します。
Blenderでは3Dモデルを変形や結合していわゆる『3Dキャラクター』を作成し、それをキーフレームという手法で時間単位のアニメーションを定義して動かすことができます。
Blenderを使って作成したモデルとアニメーションは[glTF 2.0](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlTF)というフォーマット(拡張子は`*.glb`など)で出力可能です。
※Wikipediaには「glTF (GL Transmission Format) はJSONによって3Dモデルやシーンを表現するフォーマットである。」と書かれていますが、Blenderから出力したファイルを開くと中身はバイナリです。
[Blenderから出力し、モデルを単純に読み込む例](https://www.pentacreation.com/blog/2019/09/190916.html)

このglTFフォーマットのファイルをThree.jsから読み取ってJavaScriptからアニメーション操作を呼び出すことでWeb上で動作させることができます。
[コード例](https://www.pentacreation.com/blog/2019/10/191016.html)

インタラクティブに動作させる仕組みは別のご質問[glbファイルについて](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/67985)もご参照ください。

Comment: glTF 2.0フォーマットの拡張子が.glbに該当するのですね(両者の違いが良く分かっていませんでした)。また、アニメーション内容はJavaScriptで記述しているものと思っていたのですが、JavaScriptではアニメーション操作を呼び出しているだけなのですね…