# glbファイルについて

Tags: three.js

Three.jsで「glbファイル」を読み込んで3Dキャラクターを動作させているコードがあるのですが、「glbファイル」とはどういうファイルですか？　どうやって作成するのですか？

テキストエディタで「glbファイル」ソースコードを確認しようとしたのですが、ファイルサイズが大きくて無理でした。

そこで、Windowsの3Dビューアー(今回初めて使いました)で「glbファイル」を開いたら、3Dが表示され、プルダウンで複数アニメーション切り替えが出来ました。
これは、1つの「glbファイル」に、3Dデータと複数アニメーションの動作が格納されている、ということですか？

Comment: "glbファイル" でgoogle検索すると「バイナルファイル」と出てきますが、ソースコードと判断されたのはなぜでしょう？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Three.jsで動作させることが可能な3Dキャラクターは、どうやって作成するのですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/67984) の[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/68008/9820)に記述した通り、glbファイルは[glTF](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlTF)というフォーマットで3Dモデルやシーン(そしてアニメーション)を記述するファイルです。

3Dモデルは大量にポリゴンの座標などの情報を含んでいるため、これを記述するには非常に大きなデータが必要です。
このためglbファイルの中身は通常で数MBを超えるバイナリベースの形式になっており、テキストエディタで人間が視認することは想定されておりません。
※glTFのWikipediaには「glTF (GL Transmission Format) はJSONによって3Dモデルやシーンを表現するフォーマット」と書かれていますが、JSONの中にバイナリデータが詰め込まれています。

ちなみに3DモデルのエディタであるBlenderのソースコード(*.blendファイル)もバイナリベースなのでエディタで書き換えることが前提となっています。テキストエディタで書き換えることは実質不可能です。

glTFには複数のアニメーションを格納することができ、[animationsという配列](https://qiita.com/syoyo/items/236f2a4713aa381c6735#animations)を選択して切り替えることができます。
切り替えのためにThree.jsでは[AnimationMixer#clipAction](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/animation/AnimationMixer.clipAction)というメソッドが用意されています。
おそらくご質問の3Dビューアーも同様の仕組みでプルダウンの項目を読み取って表示しているはずです。

参考資料: [Three.jsを用いたモデルのアニメーション切り替え](https://qiita.com/sawa-zen/items/05ff33a3531f469b29ef)

Comment: 色々勘違いしていたことに気が付きました。モデルは単なる座標データなので軽い、と思い込んでいたのですが、3Dモデルになるとそうではないのですね。「3DモデルのエディタであるBlenderのソースコード(*.blendファイル)もテキストエディタで書き換えることは実質不可能」とのことなので、Blenderソフトウェアでアニメーションまで作り込み、表示やアニメーション切替部分だけをJavaScriptで操作する、という感じですね…

Comment: ご賢察の通りです。Blenderはリッチな3Dデータを作成できる分、単なる座標データにとどまらず「色や輝度や光源の位置」「cmやinch単位の縮尺」「質量」などのデータを内部に持てるので軽くはなりません。Three.jsでglTFを動かす時はJavaScriptからアニメーションの種類を選択し、選択したアニメーションをスタートする命令を呼び出す形ですね。